# How to make simple web dialog for web page

Tags: java, javascript, html

I'm new in the web programing. I'm making a web side and I wan to use lots of web dialogs like the ones in tweeter or fb. They are not pop-up windows and I guess can't be blocked by the browser. I have try to find some information about how to make this dialogs but can't find something useful for me. Can you place help me to solve my problem. 
I have menage to make some very simple one :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function myDialog() {
   alert("Thanks for clcking the button");  
   }
  </script>
<input type="button" onclick="myDialog()" />
```

but this is just a message. I need one dialog for log-in and make a new post and...
Btw I'm using spring mvc for this project.
Thanks in advice!

Comment: You should most likely look into a library like jQuery UI for that, when it comes to dialogs there is a small player called Apprise that is very useful, http://labs.bigroomstudios.com/libraries/Apprise-v2

Comment: Use jquery dialog http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery dialog for this.Check the information in the below url 
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Eric Martin's [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one i whipped together.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function showHide(obj) {
   var div = document.getElementById(obj);
   if (div.style.display == 'none') {
     div.style.display = '';
   }
   else {
     div.style.display = 'none';
   }
 }



</script>





Then call it like so:

Code:
<a href="#" onclick="showHide('hidden_div'); return false;">Some Text</a>

<div id="hidden_div" style="display: none; text-align: center; vertical-align:middle; opacity:0.9;background-color:#ccc; position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:1000;">
<br/><br/><br/>
Hi there I am a message.
<br/>
<a href="#" onclick="showHide('hidden_div'); return false;">Close with an url.</a>
<br/>
Or
<br/>
<input type="button" onclick="showHide('hidden_div'); return false;" value="Close with a button">
<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the example. It's what just what I need. And

Comment: Don't forget to give me the answer is useful option LOL.. (^_^) I am glad it works..

Comment: <table align="center" width="400" bgcolor="f8f8ff" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" >
      <tr>
        <td align="right" width="100">User:</td>
          <td width="100">
            <input type="text" />
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td align="right" width="100">Password:</td>
          <td width="100">
           <input type="text"/>
          </td>       
       </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <input type="button" align="center" value="SignIn" onclick="showHide('hidden_div'); return false;">
 </div>

Comment: This is simple table that I just have made by your example. It look nice :) I guess If I don't want the bgcolor effect, I can set remove it because I wan to get effect like the dialogs on twitter - I like twitter style :)